# yield statment behaviour in a generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, generator, yield

Learning about generators I've got this [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators) :

```
function* fibonacci() {
  var fn1 = 0;
  var fn2 = 1;
  while (true) {  
    var current = fn1;
    fn1 = fn2;
    fn2 = current + fn1;
    var reset = yield current;
    if (reset) {
        fn1 = 0;
        fn2 = 1;
    }
  }
}

var sequence = fibonacci();
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 5
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 8
console.log(sequence.next(true).value); // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
```

I appreciate an elaborate text to answer the following questions together :
Why is `reset` tested falsy after all those `yield current` assigned to it?
that leads to a more general question:
How does `yield` behave in assignment?
Where exactly does a value passed to `next()` go?
because here in this code

```
function *createIterator() {
 let first = yield 1;
 let second = yield first + 2; // 4 + 2
 yield second + 3; // 5 + 3
}
let iterator = createIterator();
console.log(iterator.next()); // "{ value: 1, done: false }"
console.log(iterator.next(4)); // "{ value: 6, done: false }"
console.log(iterator.next(5)); // "{ value: 8, done: false }"
console.log(iterator.next()); // "{ value: undefined, done: true }"
```

now I replace `yield first + 2` by `yield (first + 2)` and still got the same results. So what is the mechanics behind that?

A step by step detailed answer would be golden since I'm new to this programming style.
I repeat for the speed readers: please help me understand how Javascipt execute such code instruction by instruction, thanks

Comment: Have you read the article you linked?

Comment: The article says "The next() method also accepts a value which can be used to modify the internal state of the generator. A value passed to next() will be treated as the result of the last yield expression that paused the generator." That's the exact answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `yields` is assigned it has two uses:

### The first is its primary use:

It determine each object returned by the `next()` method of the iterator.

### The second is when assigned:

The trickiest part to understand is that the primary role of yield is performed here first (the right part of an assignment). then the generator code freezes. The next time `next()` is called it resumes its execution. With first assigning the **current** `next()` argument to the left part of the assignment.

Knowing that and that:

> Each time the generator's next() method is called, the generator
>   resumes execution and runs until it reaches one of the following:
>
> A yield, which causes the generator to once again pause and return the generator's new value. The next time next() is called,
>   execution resumes with the statement immediately after the yield.
>   ...

Here's what execution of the second example looks like :

```
iterator.next()--->>>
yields 1
//next returns 1 in the 'value' property
//Freezing until the next call to next
iterator.next(4)--->>>
let first =4
yield first + 2;
//next returns 6 in the 'value' property
//Freezing until the next call to next 
iterator.next(5)--->>>
let second = 5
yield second + 3;
// That is 8 in the value property
```

useful links :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next
- Some insights and the second example was taken from Nicholas C. Zakas's book : Understanding ECMAScript 6